# 403 message on json request in django

Tags: jquery, django, json, django-urls, http-status-code-403

I am running django server and when I do a post I get a 403 message. My question is that to make a json call as shown below should I be running apache? Or else, what am I doing wrong?

In the html page I have included the latest jquery file only.

```
 var snddata = {};
  snddata["username"] = username;
  snddata["firstname"] = firstname;
  snddata["lastname"] = lastname;
  snddata["usertype"] = $("#usertype").val();
  snddata["address"] = address;
  snddata["emailid"] = emailid;
  snddata["empid"] = empid;
  $.post("/home/", snddata, 
     function callbackHandler(data, textstatus) 
     {
     if (data.status == 1)
     {
        alert("User added successfully");
     }
     else 
     {
        alert(data.msg);
     }
     }, 
     "json"
     );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django has a csrf protection and you must to put "csrfmiddlewaretoken" for every POST request.
Try to add this line of code:

```
snddata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
```

You must insert this tag in your form, wich returns a hidden input field with csrf_token:

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

Comment: But i do not see the request in /home i have defined def home(request): logging.debug("Got request") i so not see the above the debug statement
 
Should i be including any js file to make the json call

Comment: still the same issue after including this

Comment: Setting `snddata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"]` in that way will not work, because the template tag returns a form input element, not the required token.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right about the template tag {% csrf_token %}, it returns a hidden input with csrf token

Comment: I did both the js addition and adding the csrf_token to my html and I still am getting a 403 error. What else could be missing? Should I put this as a separate question?

Answer (score 2):

To add to what Alasdair said.

Add `{% csrf_token %}` somewhere on the html page. And add `snddata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = $("#csrfmiddlewaretoken").val();` to the javascript above.

This should add a 'input' element with the CSRF Token as the value. And the js part will submit that in the form.

CSRF token is needed with POST requests unless the view has the `@csrf_exempt` decorator or if CSRF has been disabled.

The response code 403 is a Forbidden request code.

Comment: willfill updated his answer. It should be `$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();`

Answer (score 1):

The 403 error is because of Django's Cross Site Request Forgery protection (CSRF) protection.

See the [Django CSRF docs page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) for more details, which includes a useful snippet you can use to make jQuery ajax requests work.

Comment: But i do not see the request in /home i have defined def home(request): logging.debug("Got request") i so not see the above the debug statement

Comment: Should i be including any js file to make the json call

Comment: Your view with the debug statement is never called because the CSRF middleware checks for the token first, and returns the 403.

Comment: Can u please point me as to what am i suppose to do in the template i.e,html file ..i do not have a form in the html file  but i do have included snddata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"] = "{% csrf_token %}";
 and still the same issue

Comment: Setting `snddata["csrfmiddlewaretoken"]` in that way will not work, because the template tag returns an form input element, not the required token. Include the ajax snippet included in the docs that I linked to. You can put it in a separate js file, or include it in at the top of your `<script>` tag in your template.